# Restful API for a git-versioned wiki

Tags: python, git, rest, wiki, tastypie

I'm trying to design a URL scheme for a wiki that has the following properties:

- Markdown syntax
- pages
- page sections (defined by header structure)
- git-versioned using pygit2

I have to following scheme at the moment:

```
/page/
/page/:name/
/page/:name/section/
/page/:name/section/:id/
```

but it doesn't take into account the revisions. Revisions are useful to list the history of page changes, but also to checkout specific page revisions and so on. So I'm wondering how you would include them in the api.

Thanks

Comment: [gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) did the same thing but written in ruby